# OData Query on EntityType

Tags: odata

I apologize for my poor English.

I have a system that I call by OData queries. I got the schema with $metadata. So I have all the EntityType, Function, EntityContainer ...

But when the following query :

```
.../EntityType?$filter=Name eq "type_000001"
```

The error is :

```
{"error":{"code":null, "message": "Cannot find EntitySet, Singleton, ActionImport or FunctionImport with name 'EntityType'."}}
```

No matter how much I read the documentation on building queries, I can't find items. (https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html)

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to put the `EntitySet` from your metadata instead of `EntityType`:

```
.../EntityType?$filter=Name eq "type_000001"
```

You are trying to request data from an entity, but that specific entity does not exists.

At least this is what the error says.